# Chrome extension code to hide tabs on Chrome for Mac when in fullscreen

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to programmatically launch fullscreen which works fine on Chrome for Windows, but on Chrome for Mac, the tabs and address bar are still shown when in 'fullscreen' mode. The equivalent 'fullscreen mode' on Mac seems to be called 'presentation mode' but how can you obtain this programmatically (i.e. without using  View > Enter Presentation Mode (⇧+⌘+F). Either that, or how can you hide the tabs/address bar when in fullscreen mode?

The code I'm currently using:

```
 chrome.windows.getCurrent(null, function(window) {
    chrome.windows.update(window.id, {state: "fullscreen"});
  })
```

Related discussion in this question: [How to Auto-Hide the Address Bar in Google Chrome?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/50762/how-to-auto-hide-the-address-bar-in-google-chrome)

Comment: This may be a point in the right direction. In Chrome menus uncheck "View->Always Show Toolbar in Full Screen" to get rid of the tabs and address bar. I'm not sure how to do this programmatically though.